# How do I can Institution javascript code in the form of class, namespace (same C#)

Tags: javascript, css, class, namespaces

I have many javascript, CSS file, I want to use namespace, institution code in the form of class (same C#) for easy control it.

Can I do it, may everyboy give me some idea!

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.Do you mean that you want to crate a JS project using class based syntax ?

Comment: sorry, My mean is can we create class for javascript, css. So i can easy control it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to organize CSS and Javascript.

Use a CSS preprocessor language (e.g. LESS/CSS, SASS, SCSS).
Preprocessor languages use variables and imports for namespace as imports. 
Look on sites for more information.

JavaScript supported namespaces on ECMA5. Use TypeScript, work clean and support all Browsers. Look on Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) sites.